# Is the 3000T's case made by Commodore, or was it stock from elsewhere?

Tags: amiga, case, amiga-3000

Is the 3000T's case made by Commodore, or was it stock from elsewhere?  I need a side panel for one.

Comment: What's a 'sidd' panel?

Comment: I'm guessing typo for “side”

Comment: Yes, ^sidd^side^.  Typo, sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The case of the Amiga 3000T was actually modified from the Commodore PC-60 III (their top-range PC). I doubt, however, that this makes it an easier find. Those monsters are sought after as well, apparently.

Commodore was still fully functional when the PC-60 and 3000T were produced, so it is very unlikely a generic stock item from a third-party supplier.

Comment: Gives me another item to look for, at least.  Thanks!